# Como uma alterar o layout de uma pagina sem mexer no código fonte?

Tags: javascript, html

O código abaixo faz o seguinte: Quando clico no botão <kbd>**Mostrar Botão**</kbd> um outro botão aparece, porém, vamos supor que eu clique <kbd>F5</kbd>, o botão desaparece.

Que ferramenta eu poderia usar para que isso não acontecesse e o botão ficasse ali mesmo após o <kbd>F5</kbd> ou até eu criar outro botão para escondê-lo novamente?

```js
function mostrarBt() {
  document.getElementById("botao1").style.display="block";
}
```

```css
button#botao1 {display: none; margin-top: 5px;}
```

```html
<button id="mostrar" onClick="javascript: mostrarBt();">Mostrar Botão</button>
<button id="botao1">Botão 1</button>
```

Comment: bote tudo isso dentro de uma div, dê um `id` á ela e use document.getElementById(id_da_div).innerHTML. Use o `innerHTML`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Existem muitas maneiras de se fazer isso, a mais correta seria armazenar a escolha do usuario no banco de dados, dessa forma sempre que o usuario atualiza-se, ele teria a pagina da maneira que escolheu (com o botão nesse exemplo).

Outra forma, seria utilizando `localStorage`, um exemplo bem simples de como fazer isso.

```js
if(!localStorage.button){
  document.getElementById('outButton').style.display = 'none'
}else{
  document.getElementById('outButton').style.display = 'block'
}

   
document.getElementById('show').onclick = function(){
    document.getElementById('outButton').style.display = 'block'
    localStorage.button = true
}
```

```css
#outButton{
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<button id="show">Mostrar Outro Botão</button>

<button id="outButton">MEU OUTRO BOTAO</button>
```

Lembrando que você não vai conseguir testar no `Sandbox`, mas pode testar nesse [link](http://jsbin.com/vexetuyihe/1/edit?html,js,console,output)

Comment: Obrigado, nunca usei localStorage, mas vou ir testando aqui as possibilidades

Answer (score 1):

Use `localStorage` para guardar informações no navegador e depois usá-las:

Exemplo no [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nd6Lsea1/):

**CSS:**

```
button#botao1 {display: none; margin-top: 5px;}
#esconder{ display: none; margin-top: 5px; }
```

**HTML:**

```
<button id="mostrar" onClick="javascript: mostrarBt();">Mostrar Botão</button>
<button id="esconder" onClick="javascript: escondeBt();">Esconder Botão</button>
<button id="botao1">Botão 1</button>
```

**JS:**

```
window.onload = function(){
    if(localStorage.mostrabotao2){
        mostrarBt();
    }

}

function mostrarBt() {
  document.getElementById("botao1").style.display="block";
  document.getElementById("esconder").style.display="block";
  localStorage.mostrabotao2 = 1;
}

function escondeBt() {
  document.getElementById("botao1").style.display="none";
  document.getElementById("esconder").style.display="none";
  localStorage.clear();
}
```

O código acima salva a informação "1" (pode ser qualquer informação, o importante é que o `localStorage` tenha algum valor, até mesmo um *true* -- `localStorage.mostrabotao2 = true;`) no `localStorage` e verifica se ele possui valor toda vez que a página é carregada. Se existe valor, o botão é exibido, se não, não faz nada e o botão continua oculto pelo CSS.